# Can I iterate and update values in an object within a map in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Plain and simple I want to build a standings table for a football league. My idea is to build a map with a label (teamName) and an object (teamCompetitionStats). So I created a class like this:

```
export class TeamCompetitionStats {
    teamMatches: number;
    teamPoints: number;
}
```

And my idea is to create a map with the team name, and the team competition stats like this:

```
map('Barcelona', TeamCompetitionStats)
```

So when I iterate through each match, I check if I have the team, if not I add an entry to the map with the teamName + TeamCompetitionStats, If it is already present, I update the values within TeamCompetitionStats.

The problem is that I don't understand how can I update the values in an object within the map (In this case, TeamCompetitionStats).

Not looking for a piece of code in particular but only to review if it is possible and I'm in the right path or

is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, not ES6?

Comment: What is `map` ?

Comment: Your `TeamCompetitionStats` are mutable objects, right? Just update them.

Comment: @Bergi, it is TypeScript but map is a new technology from the es6 standard, or that is what I understand (I'm new at this). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Ah, it's just that the code you posted doesn't use a `Map`, so maybe you were referring to some other implementation (Immutable.js possibly).

Comment: Haha yeah I'm not really sure it was the right appraoch though, for the answers I'm getting and some research, I should just go with objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the object is stored with [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

If it is update said object, if not then store it.

```
let a = myMap.get(whatever)
if(a)
  updateItem(a)
else
   map.set(key, val);
```

> is there a better way to do it?

Imo, simple object is suited in this case.

```
let teams  = {"teamA": "sickteam", "teamB": "not so sick"};

if (teams["teamC"])
 teams["teamC"] = "team of clownssssss";
else
 teams["teamC"] = "team of clowns";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Check out [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Your source is your new data, the target is the overall object. If the source doesn't match anything in the target, it gets added. If it does match something in the target, it gets updated.

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.  Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.